# Conditional import in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a server application that had to be run on both Windows and Linux system.
the problem starts with [mdns/zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) modules that I use.

I use both:

1. `zeroconf` for **Linux** (https://docs.rs/zeroconf/latest/zeroconf/)
2. `astro_dnssd` for **Windows** (https://github.com/astrohq/astro-dnssd)

**Why I had to use 2 modules to do the same thing?**

I had to use 2 modules to do basically the same thing since `zeroconf` supports Linux but doesn't support Windows and `astro_dnssd` use [bonjour-compatibility layer on top of Avahi for Linux which no longer supported](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/avahi-compat.html), but `astro_dnssd` works fine on Windows

**My `main.rs`:**

```
// asto_dnssd can be compiled on both Windows and Linux, but doesn't work as intended on Linux
use astro_dnssd::DNSServiceBuilder;

// this modules doesn't even compile on Windows
// so I had to manually disable this line and everything that uses zeroconf to run my server app on Windows, including the "Cargo.toml" file
use zeroconf::prelude::*;
use zeroconf::{MdnsService, ServiceRegistration, ServiceType, TxtRecord};
```

**The problem:**

As of now, I had to manually disable `zeroconf` (by commenting the line) whenever I work on Windows and had to enable it again when I work on Linux. This is tedious work and unsustainable in the long run. Is is possible to use env variable or `env::consts::OS` to detect and make the "conditional import" in Rust? For example:

```
let current_os = env::consts::OS;
match current_os {
        "windows" => {
            use astro_dnssd::DNSServiceBuilder;
            //... the rest of the code
        }
        "linux" => {
            use zeroconf::prelude::*;
            use zeroconf::{MdnsService, ServiceRegistration, ServiceType, TxtRecord};
            // ... the rest of the code
        }
        _ => {
            panic!("This operating system is not supported yet")
        }
    };
```

Comment: so... #[cfg(target_os = "linux")] and then followed by `use xxxx` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conditional Imports**

Conditional compilation can be done with [`cfg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) in Rust.

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
use zeroconf::prelude::*;
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
use zeroconf::{MdnsService, ServiceRegistration, ServiceType, TxtRecord};

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
use astro_dnssd::DNSServiceBuilder;
```

To improve readability, you may want to put the platform-specific parts within a module.

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
mod details {
    use zeroconf::prelude::*;
    use zeroconf::{MdnsService, ServiceRegistration, ServiceType, TxtRecord};

    // Define structs, functions, ...
    pub fn perform_platform_specific_operation() {}
}

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
mod details {
    use astro_dnssd::DNSServiceBuilder;

    // Define structs, functions, ...
    pub fn perform_platform_specific_operation() {}
}

fn main() {
    details::perform_platform_specific_operation();
}
```

**Conditional Cargo Dependencies**

See [Platform specific dependncies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies) from the Cargo Book. For example, the following lines in the `Cargo.toml` does what you want (adapt the version number to your own needs).

```ini
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
astro_dnssd = "0.1.0"

[target.'cfg(unix)'.dependencies]
zeroconf = "0.1.0"
```

Comment: OK. it works in the `main.rs` but how to tell Cargo.toml to use spesific modules for each target_os ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the Cargo part.